# Object.assign results in r.Event object

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to console.log an object that has been combined from 2 other objects.  The first time I console.log(allObjects), it works and I see this:

> Object {name: "david", wineResults: "[{"Id":158020,"Name":"Antinori
>   Tignanello
>   2013","U…"List":[]},"Retail":null,"Vintages":{"List":[]}}]"}

```js
$(document).on('submit', '.add-item-form', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (event.type === 'keypress' && event.which === 13 || event.type === 'submit') {

        var name = $('#item-input').val();
        var usersObject = {
            "name": name
        };


        var searchArray = $('#search-results-array').val();
        var searchArrayObj = {
            "wineResults": searchArray
        };

        var allObjects = Object.assign(usersObject, searchArrayObj);
        console.log(allObjects); // This one works great.

        favDropDownItem(allObjects);
        FavoritesList(allObjects);

        $('#item-input').val('');
    }
```

Then in the code below, I'm trying to pass allObjects to a link that I create which appears in a drop down menu.

```js
function favDropDownItem(allObjects) {
  var output = '';

        output += "<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='dropbtn' onclick='myDropdown()'>Favorites</a>";
        output += "<div class='dropdown-content' id='myDropdown'>";
        output += "<p class='nameLink'>" + name + "</p>";
        output += "<a href='#'>sample</a>";
        output += "</div>";

        $('li.dropdown').html(output);


        $(".nameLink").on('click', function(allObjects) {
            console.log(allObjects);  // This one results in r.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", target: 
            //p.nameLink, currentTarget: p.nameLink, relatedTarget: null…}
        });
    }

});
```

When I click on .nameLink, I would hope to get the same data that appeared in the first console.log, but instead I see this:

> r.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", target: p.nameLink,
>   currentTarget: p.nameLink, relatedTarget: null…}

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the event parameter name

```
        $(".nameLink").on('click', function(e) {
            console.log(allObjects);  //now you can get correct out put here
        });
```